# Return Only Max Value With Distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I've below data in database table as follows:

**Table Data**:

```
1002    1
1002    0
```

So expected output are these:

**Condition 1**:

```
1002    1
1002    0
```

**Expected Output**:

```
1002    1
```

**Condition 2**:

```
1002    1
1002    1
```

**Expected Output**:

```
1002    1
```

**Condition 3**:

```
1002    0
1002    0
```

**Expected Output**:

```
1002    0
```

So tried it with the following that returns only 1 every time:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.ID, (SELECT MAX(K.VAL) FROM Table k WHERE K.ID = M.ID) VAL FROM Table m WHERE M.VAL = '1002';
```

Doing the join in the same table but didn't get much help. Any simple suggestion with one liner query would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX` and `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(val) AS val
FROM   table_name
WHERE  id = 1002
GROUP BY id
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ebb335f1ca20cc6e04133b6eb51183a)*

Comment: @user8512043 Yes ... but you would need to explain what you are trying to achieve because we don't understand why you would want/need to use it as a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also sort the column you want max to descend and extract the first record

```
SELECT id,val
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val desc) AS seq,
    id,val
    FROM table_name
)tb
WHERE seq = 1;
```